# Не работает метод forEach(callback) - массив не пустой и ошибок в консоль не выводит

Tags: javascript, vue.js, grid

Первый раз задаю вопрос где либо, поэтому если вдруг не хватает инфы - скажите

И так... есть такой метод:

```js
render: function() {
  console.log(this.gridSettings); // *1* [Array], length = 6

  this.gridSettings.forEach(elemSettings => {
    console.log(elemSettings); // *2* ...
    elemSettings.render(); // *3* ...
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
```

1: Выводит в консоль массив (с 6 элементами) в котором есть функция forEach (в прототипах)
2: Ничего не выводит (должен был вывести каждый элемент)
3: Ничего не делает (должно было отрендерить каждый элемент)

Ошибок так же никаких (через try...catch тоже проверял и все равно ничего)

Проблема в том, что вообще никакой код внутри этого перебора не работает и ошибок не выдает (вот просто 0 ошибок и 0 результата)

В ЧЕМ МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ ПРОБЛЕМА подскажите пожалуйста, а то я в тупике каком-то...
Гугл тоже в душе не чает, что за проблема, по этому решился все же задать вопрос тут

Comment: попробуй вывести `console.log(this.gridSettings.length);`

Comment: Уже выводил - войство 'length' имеет значение '6'. По этому и подписал в коментарии вывод лога

Comment: Вы пометили мой вопрос дубликатом другого вопроса на который уже ответили, но боюсь огорчить - это не ответ на мой вопрос
У меня проблема совсем инная

Comment: ты выводил именно `console.log(this.gridSettings.length);`? В любом случае, поправь сниппет в вопросе, чтобы проблема воспроизвелась.

Comment: console.log(this.gridSettings) что в массиве лежит?